# Eclipse CDT missing C/C++ Unit

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm tasked with hooking up Google Test in Eclipse. I got Google Test working from the command-line, but we want it working like JUnit for Java in Eclipse. This is theoretically possible. However, running through all the online instructions I can find, they all say to use Run -> Run Configurations... -> C/C++ Unit option. For the life of me, I can't find it. Everything else is in the Run Configurations dialog, just not that item.

[image]

So I figured, even though we have Eclipse for C++ Developers installed (which should contain everything that the CDT Plug-in contains), maybe it's missing the unit testing stuff. Trying to update CDT, however, just shows that the only thing missing is the Autotools stuff (which we have no need for).

Vital statistics:

- Eclipse version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
- Operating System: Linux, CentOS
- Compiler: gcc

I know that's the not the latest version of Oxygen. It's the latest we can use, because the current versions have a bug that doesn't recognize our code as valid C++.

How do I get the C/C++ Unit option in Run Configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install "C/C++ unit testing support" feature. Go to `Help` -> `Install new software`, select `All available sites` and search for it. Installing it will require Eclipse restart. After restart C++ unit test group will appear in the list of Debug configurations.

Comment: Woah, man, that was quick. Thank you! That seemed to solve it!